# Watir webdriver; looping and clicking specific number of elements

Tags: rspec, automation, each, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir webdriver and rspec, and I'm looking to create a loop that takes search results and clicks on a hardcoded number of elements (i.e., if there are 50 results, I want to click on the first 5) 
This is what I have so far:

```
asset_card = search_modal.divs(:class, 'asset-card selectable')
asset_card.each do |assets|
    assets.click
end
```

This currently goes and clicks on *all* the results that come back--is there a simple way to click on the first 5 or some other hardcoded value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object returned by the `divs` method is [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html), which provides a variety of methods for interacting with the collection.

To take the first 5, use the [`take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) method:

```
asset_card = search_modal.divs(:class, 'asset-card selectable')
asset_card.take(5).each do |assets|
  assets.click
end
```